# navigation module not showing on sub page in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I tried adding some pages in joomla but the navigation on the left disappears when following the newly add link. Please have a look [here](http://hosting01.hestronic.nl/~ijskoud2/) and notice the left navigation bar not showing under the  "Test Menu Item" (left bottom).

I have literally copied all parameters from another menu item (e.g. "MILIEU") but it doesnt seem to affect the behavior. In stead the "news archive" item is always listed in the left navigation area.

How to remove the news archive link and have the normal navigation shown?

Please help!

Joomla 1.5.25

Comment: Don't forget to go to 'extensions' -> 'module manager' and enable the menu there.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the menu assignment of the module you want to show when a menu item is selected. Check this: http://www.byte.nl/cms/images/joomlatemplatecursus/jt15_5/menu-assignment.jpg

Comment: Yup, if the module is only shown on selected menu items, you have to add the module to any new menu items you want it on after you create the new menu item.